# How do you stop client-side Socket.io from looping socket emissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Let's say I have a socket.io event called 'add' which takes 0 parameters and when received on the server side, increments a count variable and then emits the new count value to every client. How can I stop people from essentially opening up the JS console and using a loop like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    socket.emit('add');
}
```

Another scenario which may make more sense is: how can I detect flooding in, say, a chatting application?

I fully understand that there's nothing one can really do to ensure that client side code isn't manipulated by user.

How would one go about adding some form of timeout for each socketio event handler for each client?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110010/node-socket-io-anything-to-prevent-flooding

Comment: @Xodrow I've seen that, that's for throttling actual data sent to the server. I don't think it's a timeout at all. It's a mb/s throttle. I'm looking for some form of socket emit event handler that checks the previous time of each previous event from the same socket.

Comment: why not augmenting the client with `lasttime = Date.now()` and check if `lasttime - Date.now() > fixedtimeout` ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day I actually ended up doing that using a key val array to store client addresses along with previous message time and then checking if the difference between the time was less than 100ms. Submit this as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for validation :

why not augmenting the client with `lasttime = Date.now()` and check if `lasttime - Date.now() > fixedtimeout`

### or :

> using a key val array to store client addresses along with previous message time and then checking if the difference between the time was less than 100ms

:-)

Comment: I'll award this in 2 hours, SO won't let me do it yet.

Comment: Great ! no problem ! glad to help you !